# how pass inputs before javascript execution, WITHOUT PROMPTING IN TERMINAL

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, interpreter, brainfuck

i have the following code:

```
'use strict';

// const exec = require('child_process').exec
var brainfuck = require('brainfuck')
let source = '>,[>,]<[.<]'
brainfuck.exec(source, function(err, output) {
    console.log(process.argv)
    console.log(output)
})
```

it is an brainfuck interpreter, that take inputs until a 'null' value is passed, so the code stops, then all code is reversed, printing to user.

when i run, i'm asked to pass values from TERMINAL, i do want to automate this inputs without 'human interation', as i wanna run thousands of tests, so my code will decide what to pass as inputs when asked.

[image]

[image]

EDIT3: brainfuck interpreter i'm using: github.com/rajkissu/brainfuck

which is a javascript interpreter

Comment: Can you provide a link to the brainfuck module you're using? Maybe it provides a way to supply alternate input. As far as I can tell, `node.js` doesn't have a built-in way of redirecting stdin.

Comment: https://github.com/rajkissu/brainfuck

Comment: Unfortunately, that implementation is hard-coded to use `process.stdin`, and node.js doesn't provide a way to redirect that itself.

Comment: sugestions? I also have some interpreters in c++ which use some different flux, but, also working not as expected.

Comment: the hard code is here:

https://github.com/rajkissu/brainfuck/blob/master/lib/brainfuck.js

Comment: I know you don't like it, but my best suggestion is to write a simple shell script to run node.js with input redirected from a string.

Comment: Either that or modify the brainfuck implementation to allow you to provide the input as a parameter instead of reading it from process.stdin.

Comment: Here is my second interpreter i'm using: https://github.com/fabianishere/brainfuck

Comment: I need to pass the inputs inside the code, as i'll run it several hundred times in neural network

Comment: Can't you do that with a loop in a shell script?

Comment: None of these brainfuck implementations has a way to redirect input themselves, it needs to be done before calling them.

Comment: this would decrease a lot the performance. 

const { spawnSync } = require('child_process');
let child = spawnSync('brainfuck', ['-e', '>,[>,]<[.<]'], { input: 'hello' })
console.log('stdout ', child.stdout);

here is my code running with the second interpreter (c++) written

Comment: i can pass the input in the second interpreter, but result is: 

stdout  <Buffer 68> (just the first input "h")

Comment: i would need to pass many inputs, 1 input each time and then pass a ^@ (null) character to finish loop

Comment: Sorry, I give up.

Comment: i could solve the problem with the second interpreter, the one i posted here in the commentaries, just changed { input: 'hello' } to { input: 'h\ne\nl\nl\no' }